# Improving convergence of the Newton-Raphson method

Tags: numerical-methods, nonlinear-optimization, nonlinear-system, newton-raphson

How can the Newton-Raphson method (that is, the multivariate generalization of Newton's method, used in the solution of nonlinear systems) be improved so as to attain better convergence? As-is, in most cases a fairly good initial value is required to ensure convergence.

Note that I'm aware other method exist. Here, I'm simply interested in alterations/modifications to Newton's method.

Answer (score 1):

If you want faster than Newton, the next step is Halley method.

It is amazing since, on yesterday, I found a [very recent paper](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/220492569_Computational_Implementation_of_the_Multivariate_Halley_Method_for_Solving_Nonlinear_Systems_of_Equations) on this topic (which is also among my concerns).

For Householder, [another paper](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/264833135_Modified_of_Householder_Iterative_Method_for_Solving_Nonlinear_Systems/link/5de4aec5299bf10bc3376b6f/download).

Comment: @Moo. More than 50% of my ativity over the last 50+ years is dedicated to speed up convergence for solving systems of nonlinear equations.

Comment: @Moo. Why ? I am still working on it.

Comment: @moo. Sorry ! I probably used the wrong word (my English is not fantastic, I know). What I was trying to mean is that I am **very** interested by the paper.